# Airplane change of distance from the ground

Tags: calculus

> A plane takes off at an angle of $\ 30^o. $At what rate does the plane move away from the ground (vertically) if its speed is 800 km/h

So it's just like a right triangle where $\ x $ is the distance (horizontally), $\ y$ is the vertical distance and $\ \theta = 30 $ so $\ \tan\theta = \frac{x}{y} $ and deriving it I get

$$\ sec^2(\theta) = \frac{x\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}-y\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}}{x^2} \\ x^2\cdot \sec^2(\theta) = x\cdot \frac{dy}{dt} - y \cdot\frac{dx}{dt} \\ x = \cos\theta, y=\sin \theta, \frac{dx}{dt} = 800 km/h \\$$

Then I get the wrong answer. What am I missing?

Comment: **Hint:** The vertical component of the speed is $800\sin 30^\circ=400 \text{ ms}^{-1}$.

Comment: okay but then $\ x^2 \cdot \sec^2(\theta) = cos(\theta) \cdot dy/dt - sin(\theta) \cdot 800 \rightarrow 1 + 800\sin(30^o) = cos30 \cdot dy/dt \rightarrow (1 + 400)/cos30^o = dy/dt $ which gives me $\ 534 $ while the answer is $\ 400 $

Comment: I just stated that the answer is $400$ m/s! When you move $800$ m at an angle of $30^\circ$, you move $400$ m vertically and thus we can see that it moves $400$ m away from the ground every second, giving a rate of $400 \text{ ms}^{-1}$

Comment: It is not true that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 800~\text{km}/\text{h}$ since $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is only the horizontal component of the plane's velocity, not its velocity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @N.F.Taussig so how should I express y (the vertical component) ? I thought $\ csc(\theta) = \frac{r}{y} $ but then again I get wrong answer.

Comment: If the velocity is $\boldsymbol{v}$, the horizontal component of the velocity is $\boldsymbol{v}\cos\theta$ and the vertical component of the velocity is $\boldsymbol{v}\sin\theta$, which is how Raptor obtained the answer.  This is not a related rates question.

Comment: This is much better! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dt}\tan\theta = \sec^2\theta\,\frac{d\theta}{dt},$ not just $\sec^2\theta.$ It doesn't make any sense to take a derivative with respect to $\theta$ since $\theta$ a constant $30.$ In fact, that implies $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = 0,$ so what we really get by taking derivatives of $\tan\theta$ and $\frac xy$ is the fact that $x \frac{dy}{dt} = y \frac{dx}{dt}.$ If you work out what $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is and find the values of $x$ and $y$ at any point along the path, you'll find that equation is true. But sometimes we find true statements that aren't very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that if $\ \theta $ is constant then $\ \frac{d\theta}{dt} = 1 $ and not $\ 0 $.